# Rails 4: How do I handle a submitted form where nothing was selected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Sorry if the title is a little confusing. I have a form for an `Item` with the field `name`. There's a text field where the user can input a name and submit it. But if the user doesn't type in anything and hits submit, Rails gives me a `param not found: item` error, and I'm not sure who to get around this.

items_controller.rb

```
def new
  @item = Item.new()

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @item }
  end
end

def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      format.html { redirect_to items_path }
      format.json { render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new', :notice => "Input a name." }
      format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:name)
end
```

app/views/items/new.html.haml

```
= form_for @item do |f|
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.submit "Submit"
```

The params.require(:item) part is what is causing the error. What the convention for handling the error when params[:item] isn't present?

Comment: you should not get this error, what's the params posted when you see the log?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's late for an answer but i'll still write it for someone else. As stated in [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples) you need to use fetch instead of require in strong parameters, by using fetch you can provide a default value if nothing is passed as input. Something like:

```
params.fetch(:resource, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Scaffolded rails4 app:
https://github.com/szines/item_17751377

It works if a user keep name field empty when create a new item...

Looks, it works without problem...

Development.log shows that parameters would be the following if user keep a field empty:

```
"item"=>{"name"=>""}
```

There is always something in the hash...

As Mike Li already mentioned in a comment, something wrong... because shouldn't be empty this params[:item]...

You can check if something nil, with `.nil?` , in this case `params[:item].nil?` will be `true` if it is `nil`. Or you can use .present? as sytycs already wrote.

**Previous answer:**

If you have situation when :item is empty, you should just use params[:item] without require.

```
def item_params
  params[:item].permit(:name)
end
```

More information about require in strong_parameters.rb source code:

```
# Ensures that a parameter is present. If it's present, returns
# the parameter at the given +key+, otherwise raises an
# <tt>ActionController::ParameterMissing</tt> error.
#
#   ActionController::Parameters.new(person: { name: 'Francesco' }).require(:person)
#   # => {"name"=>"Francesco"}
#
#   ActionController::Parameters.new(person: nil).require(:person)
#   # => ActionController::ParameterMissing: param not found: person
#
#   ActionController::Parameters.new(person: {}).require(:person)
#   # => ActionController::ParameterMissing: param not found: person
def require(key)
  self[key].presence || raise(ParameterMissing.new(key))
end
```

Comment: This is giving me a `undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass` error. What do I do if params[:item] isn't just empty, but itself is also nil?

Comment: I scaffolded a rails app to figure out what could be your problem. You can find here: https://github.com/szines/item_17751377

Answer (score 0):

I personally have not switched to strong parameters so I'm not sure how one should handle something like:

```
 params.require(:item).permit(:name)
```

but you can always check for item presence with something like:

```
if params[:item].present?
   …
end
```